# Retrieve the list of URLs open in Chrome tabs with Python on Windows with the ability to modify some

Tags: python, google-chrome, ui-automation

I am looking for a method to retrieve the URLs opened in Chrome on Windows using a Python script, with the ability to redirect certain URLs to a specific URL. For example, if a tab contains 'google.com', I can replace it with 'bing.com'

Thank you

Comment: Try [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)

Comment: Thank you but selenium require webdriver install. I would like to do it without using any automation program.